# string matching from unicode text file? python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode

```
import re, codecs
import string
import sys
stopwords=codecs.open('stopwords_harkat1.txt','r','utf_8')
lines=codecs.open('Corpus_v2.txt','r','utf_8')
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip().lstrip()
    #print line
    tokens = line.split('\t')
    token=tokens[4]

    if token in stopwords:
            print token
```

this code has no errors but it not work for string matching from different files.anyone can help me please?

$ i also tried the method match but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to load contents file, not only open it.

Replace following line:

```
stopwords = codecs.open('stopwords_harkat1.txt','r','utf_8')
```

with:

```
with codecs.open('stopwords_harkat1.txt','r','utf_8') as f:
    # assuming one stop word in one line.
    stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in f)

    # Otherwise, use the following line
    # stopwords = set(word for line in f for word in line.split())
```

Comment: i try it but this error present: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\remove stop words\remove\remove.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(codecs.open('stopwords_harkat1.txt','r','utf_8'))as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

Comment: @msm, The leading `open(` was typo. I updated the answer. Please check it out.